# Extract a part of a directory in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I know that similar questions were previously asked but I couldn't find what I need.

For example I have a directory /home/user/dir that contains 5 folders named from 1 to 5.

I need to create a list that will have the following form ['dir/1', 'dir/2','dir/3','dir/4','dir/5'].

I am using Python 3.5 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is something that can help you.

```
import glob
dirs = glob.iglob('whatever/the/path/*')
dir_list = ['dir/'+dir for dir in dirs]
```

In case you have a './' shown before every of you dir, you can easily do

```
dir_list = ['dir/'+dir[2:] for dir in dirs]
```

to remove them.